# Permission denied creating dir.. user in group

Tags: linux, permissions

This seems like it's probably going to be a stupid question.

I am trying to create a subdir in a directory which is owned by a different user; but the group is the same that I belong to.  What am I missing that would allow my user jones to create a dir owned by smith:developers

```
jones@server:/var$ ls -ltr
drwxrwx---  2 smith developers  4096 2013-08-19 08:41 test

jones@server:/var$ mkdir /var/test/test
mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/test/test': Permission denied

jones@server:/var$ groups jones
jones : jones developers
```

Comment: OK. If I had read just a bit more, I wouldn't have had to ask the question.

Once I logged out, and logged back in, I was able to create the directory.

Comment: If you have resolved your problem, please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: I tried.. new user, so Superuser told me I had to wait 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

OK. If I had read just a bit more, I wouldn't have had to ask the question.

Once I logged out, and logged back in, I was able to create the directory.